# On tab selection change other tabs icons and change the color of the tab text programmatically in android

Tags: java, android, view, tabs, android-tabhost

I have developed tabbedview with custom layouts for each individual tab.Now when I select one tab other tabs icons should change and I want to change the color of the other tabs text. please help?

Here is my code:

```
          final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
         tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tab_one));
         tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tab_two));
         tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tab_three));
         tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tab_four));


    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final TabViewAdapter adapter = new TabViewAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: add your code please

Answer (score 0):

```
    // - set a tab listener to your tabLayout
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {  
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabUnselected(tab);
            }
            // - this method will get execute if you select some tab
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabSelected(tab);
                // - here change the color or image of your tab which is selected and of unselected also
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this tabSelectedTextColor="yourColor" and but you own style on Value-> style

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/red" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can visit this wonderfull article on Material Tab layout in androidhive.com http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Just go through the article and learn how to change Tab icons and color. 
For changing it on view Pager item, You can set a `PageChangeListener` in View pager and update the tabs  as per new page. If further any query please feel free to comment.